# Может ли Eslint проверять код, написанный на JQuery?

Tags: jquery, frontend, eslint

И если может, то что нужно для этого сделать? Тогда, пожалуйста, пример конфигурационного файла. А если не может, то как сделать так, чтобы Eslint не обращал внимания на jQuery. Спасибо!)

Answer (score 1):

Просто нужно добавить

```
{"extends": "jquery"}
```

Comment: То есть, если у меня, присутствует в файле jquery и js совместно, jquery можно не трогать, а js нужно проверять, то можно просто в extends jquery поставить и все. Я так сделал, линтер вообще перестал что-либо проверять. Может нужно еще какой плагин установить и/или в extends массив поставить с разными настройками, как здесь "extends": [
        "jquery",
        "airbnb-base"
    ]